# error while assigning new geometry in geodataframe

Tags: python, gis, geopandas, shapely

I´m facing some problem while trying to assing a new geometry in a geodataframe.

My original geodataframe geometry was LINESTRING Z and I did transform it to LINESTRING, but I cannot assing the new geometry.

My code:

```
for i in range(len(SHP)):
    l = SHP.at[i, "geometry"]
    a = shapely.ops.transform(lambda x, y, z=None: (x, y), l).wkt
    SHP.at[i, "geometry"] = a
```

I get: Value should be either a BaseGeometry or None, got LINESTRING

I have also tried:

```
for i in range(len(SHP)):
    l = SHP.at[i, "geometry"]
    a = shapely.ops.transform(lambda x, y, z=None: (x, y), l).wkt
    SHP.at[i, "newgeometry"] = a

SHP = SHP.set_geometry(SHP["newgeometry"])
```

And then I get: Input must be valid geometry objects: LINESTRING

I don´t know what I´m doing wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this via:

```
df = SHP.set_geometry(
    SHP.geometry.map(
        lambda linestring: shapely.ops.transform(lambda x, y, *_: (x, y), linestring)
    ))
```